# Invariants of a matrix under Permutation group

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-theory, permutation-matrices

I'm interested in the invariants of a symmetric matrix under the group of permutation matrices. This is a subgroup of the group of orthogonal matrices, for which there are results on Google, but I'm interested in this particular subgroup.

To be more precise, I'm looking for invariants for the action $PAP^t$ where $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $P$ is a permutation matrix. The case where $P$ is orthogonal is known.

Comment: Do you mean the matrices which commute with all permutation matrices ? If so, such matrices are constant on the diagonal and constant off the diagonal.

Comment: I mean invariants under the group action $PAP^t$, where P is a permutation matrix. I forgot to add that A is symmetric.

Comment: Do you mean $PAP^t=A$ for all $P$ ? Observe that $P^t=P^{-1},$ hence $PA=AP.$

Comment: No, I mean two matrices $A$ and $B$ will be equivalent if $B = PAP^t$. A typical example is the determinant, the eigenvalues and the Jordan canonical form. Two equivalent matrices will have these same invariants. Is there a characterization of all invariants?

Comment: I do not know if such characterization is known for permutation equivalence. The invariants you mentioned hołd for invertible matrices $P.$

Comment: One can further restrict the invariants when $P$ is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

Two points that you might find interesting.

First, any symmetric matrix can be interpreted as the adjecency matrix of a graph (undirected), potentially with self-loops. Two symmetric matrices will be permutation similar (i.e. will correspond to the same orbit) if and only if their corresponding graphs are isomorphic. Thus, any invariant can be interpreted as a property of this weighted graph, and conversely any property of this weighted graph defines an invariant.

Second, it is notable that for a matrix whose diagonal entries are distinct, there is a unique element of its equivalence class whose diagonal entries are in increasing order.

Comment: The origin of my question is actually about understanding invariants for graphs.

Comment: I'm not sure why you decided to bury the lede, then. If there's more context that you haven't put in your question, then you should probably add it in. Anyway, as you already seem to know orthogonal invariants are also permutation invariant. There aren't any permutation-specific invariants that arise outside of the discussion of graphs and Markov chains.

Comment: I was interested in invariants for matrices. That one can interpret them as graphs is not of interest. If you happen to know a reference for such invariants, I would like to know more, regardless of whether the context is graphs or not.